# How to check odd numbers?

Tags: r

I'm beginner in R and I want separate from a list of values all odd numbers, here is what I got so far:

```
xVec <- sample(0:999, size = 250, replace = T)
oddX <- (xVec%%2!=0)
```

When I print oddX I got a list of boolean values, how do I get the numbers itself?

Comment: Try subsetting `oddX <- xVec[(xVec%%2!=0)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
xVec <- sample(0:999, size = 250, replace = T)

xVec[xVec %% 2 == 1]


  [1] 223 541 227 735 607 167 893 647 887 709 309 217 105 453 779 749 149 399 955 781 975 543
 [23] 813 675 535 645 171 717 659 941 569 161 165 811 895 177 325 611  49 451 503 263 563 403
 [45] 781 987 639 719 733 863 207 291 837 787 569 323 551 467 277 293 223 335 379 123 237 381
 [67] 591 849 449 855 163 253 867 843 477 971 543  29 381 959 691  77 623 635 131 551 489 475
 [89] 997 477 127 831 821 553  21 151 699 573 581 831 479 647 465 139 183 791 131 841 279  95
[111] 567 899 731  89 659  91 567 817 419 865 263 799 217 485 331 337  75
```

Comment: The logical expression I put in the bracket returns a logical vector the same length as `xVec`. Each element of `xVec` that meets your requirement (being an odd number) returns `TRUE` and those that don't meet the requirement returns `FALSE` if you subset your original `xVec` vector with this logical vector only those elements with corresponding `TRUE` values will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
subset(xVec, oddX)

  [1] 925 113 685 909 867 473 255 203 147 985 787 461 249 555 123 335 983 703 973
 [20] 467 119 963 311 657 915 587 925 565 331 503 847 507 243 163 629 919 935  25
 [39] 249 617 607 447 471 119 307  19 889  73 691 191 105 479 631 551 905  51 985
 [58] 169   7 487 751  73 581 469 321 345   5 151 155 653 517 221 295 229 381 347
 [77] 479  91  53 869 313 867 581 795  69 483 411 383 459  91   1 145  27 921 587
 [96] 631 367 259 745 761 323 443 409 541  31 601 729 167 727 109 269 159 927 829
[115] 531 187 373 763  19 187 655 635 495 199 881 861
```